# Offset ().top - 50% from the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it offset by 50% from the top? I also tried adding `- ($window.height()/2)`

I can set a distance of pixels `$(this).offset().top - 800)` but I want to use percentages instead. 50% was just arbitrary, it could be 25%, etc.

Here is the full script if wondering:

```js
// constants
var BTN_CLS = 'owl-thumb-item',
  BTN_ANIMATION_MILLIS = 200,
  DIV_ANIMATION_MILLIS = 1000;

// document ready handler
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  // display buttons from first 'div'
  showBtns('one', BTN_CLS);
  
  // window scroll handler
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.hidden').each(function(i, v) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top - 800) {
       // show 'div' when scrolling
  
 
  
       showDiv($(this), onCompleteDivAnimation($(this)));
      }
    });
  });

});

/**
 * Used to show an animated 'div' and perform some actions.
 * @param {Function} completeCallback Action performed after animation.
 * @param {Object} div Target element.
 */
function showDiv(div, completeCallback) {
  // check if 'div' is currently animated and avoid animation queue
  if (!div.is(':animated')) {
    div.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, {
      complete: completeCallback,
      duration: DIV_ANIMATION_MILLIS
    });
  }
};

/**
 * Used to perform actions after completing a 'div' animation.
 */
function onCompleteDivAnimation(div) {
 showBtns(div.prop('id'), BTN_CLS);
};

/**
 * Used to show button(s) from a 'div' element.
 * @param {String} divId Target element Id.
 * @param {String} btnCls Button(s) CSS class.
 */
function showBtns(divId, btnCls) {
  var btnGroup = getBtnGroup(divId, btnCls);

  animateBtn(btnGroup);
};

/**
 * Used for creating a group of button(s) from a 'div' element.
 * @param {String} divId Target element Id.
 * @param {String} btnCls Button(s) CSS class.
 * @returns {Array} btnGroup
 */
function getBtnGroup(divId, btnCls) {
  var domBtns = $('#' + divId + ' .' + btnCls),
    btnGroup = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < (domBtns || []).length; ++i) {
    btnGroup.push(domBtns[i]);
  }

  return btnGroup;
};

/**
 * Used to animate a button group that normally comes from a 'div' element.
 */
function animateBtn(btnGroup) {
 btnGroup = btnGroup || [];

  $(btnGroup.shift()).fadeIn(BTN_ANIMATION_MILLIS, function() {
    if (btnGroup.length > 0) {
      animateBtn(btnGroup);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: when you say offset 50% from the top, are you just trying to center it vertically?

Comment: A proper explanation of use case would help. It's not really clear what your goal is

Comment: Have you tried to put it into a var before your if statement? `var offElem = $(this).offset().top; var offset50 = offElem - (($window.height())/2); ***INSERT IF STATEMENT HERE***`

Comment: `$window` is undefined , it's `$(window)` unless cached as variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your on the right track with the division operator.  This works for me:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  var halfHeight = $(window).height() / 2;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > halfHeight) {
    alert("Window has reached 50%");
  }
});
```

you can change it to `$(window).scroll(function()` I just used on scroll for the fiddle demo below.

Here is a working fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/9yyse6L0/)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<style>
class fifty {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
</style>
```

If you don't always want the elements 50% from the top, use jQuery to add/remove the class.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I don't think OP wants to use it for element styles

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand; you want to show a div when you scroll 50% of the **viewport**

[image: viewport]

The following code snippet will show an modal box when you scroll past half of the **viewport**. If this is what you are intending to do then you can modify the code in the `if` statement to perform any number of actions, **the possibilities are endless**!

If this is not what you are intending to do then please feel free to elaborate.

Note: I am using `window.innerHeight` for better understanding (it has the same amount of characters as `$(window).height()`! *it also means the same thing in this scenario*). Also, I am not using jQuery (pure javascript) and I am doing some fancy `setTimeout`'s to show the modal and then fade it out after 2 seconds.

More on `window.innerHeight` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)

```js
var tHandle;

(function () {
  
  function showDiv () {
  
    var elem = document.getElementById('modal');
    
    if (tHandle) { clearTimeout(tHandle); }
    
    elem.classList.add('open');
    
    tHandle = setTimeout(function () {
      elem.classList.add('fadeIn');
      tHandle = setTimeout(function () {
        elem.classList.remove('fadeIn');
        tHandle = setTimeout(function () {
          elem.classList.remove('open');
        }, 400);
      }, 2000);
    }, 100);
    
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    
    if (scrollTop > (window.innerHeight / 2)) {
      showDiv();
    }
    
  });

})();
```

```css
#modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  transition: opacity 400ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

#modal.open {
  display: block!important;
}
#modal.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">You've scrolled past half of the window (viewport) height!</div>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>This is some text</p>
```